# GitHub: make fork an "own project"

Tags: git, github

I have found a nice GitHub project which I extended a lot. I believe my changes are good, because they are working. But it seems the original author hasn't got the time to review these changes and include them. In fact, it is even possible that the features I need and implemented are not in the vision of the original author and we simply aim at different goals. I don't know as I never got responses from him.

That said I saw my contributions are not counted in my commit-map. This is the case as long as the original repository doesn't accept my contributions. Furthermore my work is only recognized as work and doesn't attract any other people with the same vision as I have. This is the bigger problem for me, because I see a lot of people asking for these features.

I am still offering my contributions to the original project, but I see it is unlikely they are ever accepted. Now I would like to make my fork a "real project". While I plan to sync with the original project at some points of time, I want to rename it and motivate people to contribute to my project as well. In addition, I would love if GitHub would show that this project is actively maintained (speaking of the commit map). And finally, I would love to make proper releases of it.

How can I get this done and well, make my fork a full-fledged project?

Comment: I'm confused, maybe things have changed since 2014, but my TightBlog project is listed as a fork of Apache Roller in the upper left-corner: https://github.com/gmazza/tightblog, yet I'm getting full credit for all my issues, PR's, etc, even though none of work is applied to the Apache Roller main project but just to my fork: (https://github.com/gmazza?tab=overview&period=monthly).  I'm not sure what one gains by making a fork a standalone project anymore.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

> To detach the fork and turn it into a standalone repository on GitHub, contact [GitHub support](https://github.com/contact).

https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/#commit-was-made-in-a-fork

Comment: Also, doing this will keep stargazers, watchers and the network of forks. Unlike creating a new repo from scratch.

Comment: It's worth noting that GitHub Support gave me the choice of reparenting child forks or keeping them attached to my own repository.

Comment: If you write "detach fork from parent repo", you'll even be able to send your fork URL to a chatbot that will take care of opening a ticket for you. Note that you won't be able to specify the reparenting of child forks though. As see in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29326767/unfork-a-github-fork-without-deleting/41486339#comment116493608_29326840

Answer (score 43):

In order to do this you need to [duplicate the repository](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository).  The short version is:

1. Create a new repository on GitHub.
2. Clone the forked repository you want to detach from its parent.
3. Push all branches in this clone to your new repository.

Comment: If you want your repository to still have the same name, you can probably clone your repo, delete it on GitHub, create a new project with the same name, and push everything.

Comment: It seems that GitHub pull requests can only be across GitHub forks of a project. So if you duplicate your repository, you cannot make pull requests from the new repository. And if you delete and replace your old repository, all of your existing pull requests will probably be closed because GitHub will think the code was deleted, and you will be unable to make new pull requests.

Comment: Downvoting as this may mislead people to do unnecessary actions. Oleh's answer should be accepted instead: the way to go is to contact GitHub support. It took less than an hour to convert my fork into a standalone repo.

Answer (score 12):

1. Go to [Github Support](https://support.github.com/contact?tags=docs-generic)
2. Enter "detach a fork" as the subject. A prompt for the *virtual assistant* will appear — click that.

[image]

3. Follow the instructions!

[image]

#### Result

[image]

Answer (score 11):

This is super easy:

1. **Clone** the repo somewhere: `git clone git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git` (make double sure you have it cloned)
2. **Delete** the repo in GitHub (Settings > Options > Delete this repository)
3. **Create** a new blank repo in GitHub
4. `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/NEW_REPOSITORY.git` (if you used the same name for the repo, then `NEW_REPOSITORY` == `REPOSITORY` )
5. `git push`
6. 

(I use ssh, but if you use https your github urls will look like `https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git`)

Answer (score 4):

**To just transfer source code, git commits, tags and branches to a remote repo:**

1. `git clone --bare [old/source repository's git url]`

   Using [`bare`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---bare) flag, only the .git directory of the working directory is cloned.
2. `cd [recently cloned repository]`
3. `git push --mirror [new/target repository's git url]`

   Using [`mirror`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---mirror)  flag, it overwrites the target repo and pushes all the commit history, tags and branches based on the .git directory.

- At this stage, although the new repo is updated at a remote level, the local copy of it has no regular git working directory contents (source code etc) as the repository is `bare`.
- To get the new/target repository's working directory locally, one easy way would be to clone the new remote git repo again, or you could clone using the existing .git directory as mentioned below.

  `git clone [cloned .git directory at step 1] [new/target repository's directory]`

**Note:**

- This will ***not*** carry over the repository's description, pull requests,
  watchers, forks, star gazers, branch configurations like default
  branch, protected branch etc. If those data needs to be carried over, as the other answers have
  stated, contacting [GitHub support](https://support.github.com/contact?tags=docs-generic) seems to be the way.
- Idea to use bare and mirror flag to duplicate a git repo is from [this GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/duplicating-a-repository#mirroring-a-repository).
- I understand that this has been answered, but I am just adding relevant info, hoping that it might help other users.

Comment: I sent a ticket to GitHub Support and they did that quickly as I wanted to preserve the stars of the repo as well. +1

Comment: That is genius brother.

Answer (score 1):

First you should check if the licence is allowing you to do so, generally speaking Open Source enforces you to do so because it is all about software evolution whithout chains. If so then just create an new repo. Don't forget to credit the original authors and start your project.

Comment: It's MIT licensed and yes, I plan to give credits as usual. In fact I would have preferred if the original author would just have accepted my code (or told me why he doesn't)

Comment: If the license does not permit you to create a repository that isn't a GitHub fork of the original, then the project should not be a public GitHub project in the first place, since public projects are supposed to be released under an open source license. I can't think of any open source license that disallows making copies of code. That's kind of the whole point of open source. (Of course, there may be attribution requirements -- but these can be satisfied without a project being a "proper" GitHub fork.)

Comment: The author certainly *should* make their project free software, but if they do not (for example, if there is no license), then the project is non-free: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16934573/6791398