# Mirroring a repo in GitHub but running into: ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: git, github

I was trying to unfork my repo so I could set it to private and was following the instructions shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41486339/6335029

So after running `git clone --bare https://github.com/{username}/{repository}`, I then deleted the repo in GitHub and then created a new empty repo with the same name.  Then I did `cd {repository}.git` and `git push --mirror https://github.com/{username}/{repository}`.

I tried this on an old repo that I didn't care about it and it all worked flawlessly.

However, on the repo I DID care about, I get the following:

```
! [remote rejected] branch_name1 -> branch_name1 (pre-receive hook declined)
! [remote rejected] branch_name2 -> branch_name2 (pre-receive hook declined)
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

How can I resolve this??  I don't much care if I lose the other branches but I sure as heck would like `master`.

Comment: Not sure why GitHub is rejecting but do know that you can easily recover your branches by cloning a regular repository from the bare repository, by doing: `git clone {repository}.git localcopy`