# How to make PRs from a fork default to targeting the fork instead of the original?

Tags: github

Say there is an origin repo called `original/repo` of which I forked off to `my/repo`.  If I create a branch in `my/repo` and then create a PR from that branch, the PR defaults to merge to `original/repo`.  How can I make it default to merging to `my/repo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That (changing the default PR target) is a [known request](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/11729).
(11729: "Change default base repository for pull requests on forks")

But it is not supported yet by GitHub, which means you would need to

- duplicate your fork into its own GitHub independent repository, in which you can do your internal PRs, before being able to
- push to your fork, where you can do regular PR to the upstream original repository.

[Discussion 11729](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/11729#discussioncomment-7596766) does include, following [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41486339/6309) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16052477/6309):

> https://support.github.com/request?q=unfork

The alternative is a [TamperMonkey script](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/11729#discussioncomment-7745019) by [Marlen](https://github.com/klondikemarlen).

---

Q1 2024: the [same issue](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/11729#discussioncomment-8609767) also mentions (by [Andrew](https://github.com/weineran)):

> In the meantime, I have been using the gh command line tool to open the Pull Request web page with several values pre-filled.
> Here is the command I typically run:
>
> ```
> gh pr create --base main --assignee weineran --label enhancement --fill --web
> ```
>
> IIRC, the first time you run it, it will ask you to set the default repo, so be sure to select your repo, not the parent repo you forked from.