# Ownership on github and how to unfork a repository?

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows, github-for-mac

I have some questions about Github repository.

1) How to check the ownership on forked repository.
2) How to unfork a repository from my account (without deleting it from others account. I forked it recently into my account)
3) How to add users into my repository.

I tried to check the documentations on this but could not find straight answers.
Kindly suggest how to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GitHub: make fork an "own project"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390249/github-make-fork-an-own-project)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Find the forked repository under "Your repositories" and look in the upper left, you should see "forked from USERNAME/REPO_NAME" that's the repo you forked from, whoever owns that repo would be the owner. If you want to find more you can click the forked from link and then the username to go to their page.

   Example:
   https://github.com/lostphilosopher/mwphp15 - My fork
   https://github.com/MidwestPHP/mwphp15 - Original
   https://github.com/MidwestPHP - Owner's page
2. Deleting your fork only deletes your fork. The original, and all other forks, will be fine. If, however, you own the repo and it's private and others have forked it from you their forks will be deleted. See: https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repository/
3. To add a collaborator to a repo go to: https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_REPO_NAME/settings/collaboration

Answer (score 4):

for #1: what do you mean by ownership?

for #2: Go to the Settings of your forked repo and just delete it. The parent will not be touched.

for #3: Check Repo settings -> Contributors to give push rights to other github users